# Matrices Java.Llevo varios dias dandole vuelta pero no hay manera

Tags: java, matriz

Podría echarme una mano con el siguiente ejercicio. Acabo de empezar programación en Java, y tras muchas vueltas no soy capaz de dar con la resolución de este problema. He empezado de la siguiente manera, pero es obvio que no es correcto. Lo agradecería mucho. Muchas gracias.

```
 int[][] matriz = new int[10][2];
   int minutos=100000; 
   int dorsal=0;
   matriz[0][0]=3457;
   matriz[0][1]=52;
   matriz[1][0]=3467;
   matriz[1][1]=41;
   matriz[2][0]=3568;
   matriz[2][1]=39;
   matriz[3][0]=3570;
   matriz[3][1]=63;
   matriz[4][0]=3571;
   matriz[4][1]=38;
   matriz[5][0]=3572;
   matriz[5][1]=46;
   matriz[6][0]=3573;
   matriz[6][1]=59;
   matriz[7][0]=3574;
   matriz[7][1]=42;
   matriz[8][0]=3575;
   matriz[8][1]=77;
   matriz[9][0]=3576;
   matriz[9][1]=48;
        int x = 0;
 
   for (int X=0; x < matriz.length; x++){
       if (matriz[x][1] < dorsal){
       minutos=matriz[x][1];
       dorsal=matriz[x][0];  
  System.out.println("El ganador de la etapa ha sido"+dorsal+" con "+minuto
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor añade al a pregunta el código que has intentado y escribe los problemas que tienes con el mismo, tal y como aparece la pregunta podrías tener puntuaciones negativas por mal uso.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Java != javascript... asi que empieza por decidir eso.. luego.. por comparas matriz[x][1] < dorsal?? cual era la intencion ahi? despues deberias tener una matriz con 3 columnas no, porque el sexo tambien lo necesitas.. arregla todo eso.. y sentante a pensar que necesitas y queres hacer.. anda de a una cosa por vez.. como separas hombres de mujeres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes incluir el sexo en tu matriz,para poder hallar a los ganadores,donde 1 es hombre y 0 es mujer ,tomándolos en cuenta te quedaría así

```
public class competencia{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[]dorsal={3457,3467,3568,3570,3571,3572,3573,3574,3575,3576};
    int[]sexo={1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0};//1-Mas 0=Fem
    int[]edad={51,32,14,12,45,17,12,30,24,57};
    int[]minutos={52,41,39,63,38,46,59,42,77,48};

    int[][]ganadores={dorsal,sexo,edad,minutos};

    int minutosMax=1000;
    int ganador=0;
    int ganadora=0;
    int minutosM=0;
    int minutosF=0;

    for (int i=0;i<ganadores[3].length;i++ ) {
        if (ganadores[3][i]<minutosMax && ganadores[1][i]==1) {
            minutosMax=ganadores[3][i];
            ganador=ganadores[0][i];
            minutosM=ganadores[3][i];  
        }   
        
        if (ganadores[3][i]<minutosMax&&ganadores[1][i]==0) {
            minutosMax=ganadores[3][i];
            ganadora=ganadores[0][i];
            minutosF=ganadores[3][i];
        }
    }
      
    System.out.println("El ganador es "+ganador+" con "+minutosM+" minutos");
    System.out.println("La ganadora es "+ganadora+" con "+minutosF+" minutos");

}
}
```